# Strange console error when deploying React App to git pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

Hello I am getting a really strange error when I deploy React App to GitHub Pages, all my links are OK and images are in the right directories, what could be wrong?

> Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
> The attempt to bind "/meet_app/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" in the workspace failed as this URI is malformed.

[image]

Comment: I don't think the `%PUBLIC_URL%` should be literal